# Does ICS Support android.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

does ics support `android.app.Fragment`?
Whats is the major difference between v4 vs v13 for fragments?
When `android.app.Fragment` support by default android.Why there is no `android.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`? and what is the reason it supported by v13 library?

Answer (score 2):

Fragment was introduced with Honeycomb, so yes ICS supports it.  It was not supported on Gingerbread or before, except via the compatibility library.  And the differences between the various Fragments in different levels of the compatibility library is that some features were too hard or impossible to backport all the way to 4, so they backported them as far back as was reasonable.  If you need to use those features you can use the appropriate compatibility library, you just won't be able to use the app on an older platform.

Comment: Thanks my app will support above 4.0.0. so i gonna remove the supportv4 library..

Answer (score 2):

> does ics support android.app.Fragment?

Yes. Fragments were introduced in API lvl 11 (Android 3.0, Honeycomb)

> Whats is the major difference between v4 vs v13 for fragments?

Fragments from the support library are in v4 library and not in v13. The goals of the v4 libraries is to bring compatibility down to Android 1.6.

> Why there is no android.app.FragmentAdapter?

I assume you are talking about FragmentPagerAdapter since FragmentAdapter does not exist in android or in the support library. I assume FragmentPagerAdapter was introduced after and put in support library as a late addition. It is easier to add new features in a library than putting it inside the android SDK.

> what is the reason it supported by v13 library?

The lower you go in terms of compatibility the harder it is. You might lack features and have to reimplement them in order to implement your new API.

One thing to keep in mind is that support-v13 includes support-v4 as a dependency.

Comment: in the last line, support - v13 also lower than 4.0?

Comment: v13 means api level 13. Android 4.0 is api level 14. So yes. Check this link to see the android version / api level corresponding to it. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html